How to label the date based on seasons in time-series pandas dataframe?
I have a pandas dataframe with datetime and values column as below and the third column I would like to label as indicted in the df below:
|      datetime     |  |values| | Label |
| ----------------- |  | ---- | | ----- |
|2019-09-01 00:30:00|  |0.43  | |Autumn1|
|2019-09-01 01:00:00|  |0.44  | |Autumn1|
|2019-09-01 01:30:00|  |0.49  | |Autumn1|
|       :           |  |  :   | |   :   |
|2019-12-01 00:30:00|  |0.57  | |Winter1|
|2019-12-01 01:00:00|  |0.59  | |Winter1|
|       :           |  |   :  | |   :   |
|2020-01-01 00:30:00|  |0.66  | |Winter1|
|2020-01-01 01:00:00|  |0.61  | |Winter1|
|       :           |  |   :  | |   :   |
|2020-03-01 00:30:00|  |0.45  | |Spring1|
|       :           |  |  :   | |   :   |
|2020-06-01 00:30:00|  |0.32  | |Summer1|
|       :           |  |   :  | |   :   |
|2020-09-01 00:30:00|  |0.44  | |Autumn2|
|       :           |  |  :   | |   :   |
|2020-12-01 00:30:00|  |0.51  | |Winter2|
|       :           |  |  :   | |   :   |

The seasons are winter (December2019, January2020, February2020), spring (March2020, April2020, May2020), summer (June2020, July2020, August2020) and autumn (September2020, October2020, November2020).
I tried different solutions but they are not working with winter case as it was taking January2020, February2020 and December2020 for the winter. I have a dataset from September 2019 to August 2021. I want to achieve the resulting dataframe as above.
Code Tried:
# mapping months to seasons: 1- winter, 2-spring, 3-summer, 4-autumn 
    if seasons:
        seasons = {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5:2, 6:3, 7:3, 8:3, 9:4, 10:4, 11:4, 12:1} # maps months to seasons: 
        df['season'] = df['month'].map(seasons, na_action=None)
        df['winter'] = np.where(df['season'] == 1, True, False)
        df['spring'] = np.where(df['season'] == 2, True, False)
        df['summer'] = np.where(df['season'] == 3, True, False)
        df['autumn'] = np.where(df['season'] == 4, True, False)
        df['transitionperiod'] = np.where((df['season'] == 2) | (df['season'] == 4), True, False)



Please provide the code that you have tried so far together with its output and/or error messages as a minimal, reproducible example.

@JanWilamowski Please see the snapshot of the code in the question description.

it's unclear to me what you are asking. Your code snippet doesn't contain the calculation of the label which is apparently what you want. You also did not provide the actual output of your current code. Please read through the link I posted to clarify your question.

Your approach makes it very hard to have consistency. What I would suggest is to create a function that will map months to seasons, apply it and then use iterrows() to add the year-labels (1,2,3,4.....) to the seasons. Here is how you would do it (Note that my sample dataframe uses Weeks as periods, but you can change it to H (hours), D (Days), M (Months):
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'datetime': pd.date_range(start='2019-09-01 00:30:00', periods=120, freq='W'),
    'values': np.random.rand(120)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

def get_season(row):
    month = row['datetime'].month
    year = row['datetime'].year
    if month in [12, 1, 2]:
        season = 'Winter'
        if month == 12:
            season_year = year + 1  
        else:
            season_year = year
    elif month in [3, 4, 5]:
        season = 'Spring'
        season_year = year
    elif month in [6, 7, 8]:
        season = 'Summer'
        season_year = year
    elif month in [9, 10, 11]:
        season = 'Autumn'
        season_year = year

    return f"{season}{season_year}"

df['Label'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)

season_dict = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    season_name = ''.join([i for i in row['Label'] if not i.isdigit()])
    season_year = int(''.join([i for i in row['Label'] if i.isdigit()]))
    if season_name not in season_dict:
        season_dict[season_name] = {}
    if season_year not in season_dict[season_name]:
        season_dict[season_name][season_year] = len(season_dict[season_name]) + 1
    df.at[index, 'Label'] = f"{season_name}{season_dict[season_name][season_year]}"

print(df.head(20))  


This will give you
              datetime    values    Label
0  2019-09-01 00:30:00  0.729403  Autumn1
1  2019-09-08 00:30:00  0.110374  Autumn1
2  2019-09-15 00:30:00  0.436931  Autumn1
3  2019-09-22 00:30:00  0.763790  Autumn1
4  2019-09-29 00:30:00  0.477826  Autumn1
5  2019-10-06 00:30:00  0.504394  Autumn1
6  2019-10-13 00:30:00  0.011849  Autumn1
7  2019-10-20 00:30:00  0.636985  Autumn1
8  2019-10-27 00:30:00  0.075680  Autumn1
9  2019-11-03 00:30:00  0.761398  Autumn1
10 2019-11-10 00:30:00  0.557303  Autumn1
11 2019-11-17 00:30:00  0.483444  Autumn1
12 2019-11-24 00:30:00  0.380750  Autumn1
13 2019-12-01 00:30:00  0.744743  Winter1
14 2019-12-08 00:30:00  0.973454  Winter1
15 2019-12-15 00:30:00  0.556385  Winter1
16 2019-12-22 00:30:00  0.278462  Winter1
17 2019-12-29 00:30:00  0.670835  Winter1
18 2020-01-05 00:30:00  0.712285  Winter1
19 2020-01-12 00:30:00  0.298958  Winter1

and
print(df[90:120])

results in
               datetime    values    Label
90  2021-05-23 00:30:00  0.910225  Spring2
91  2021-05-30 00:30:00  0.896874  Spring2
92  2021-06-06 00:30:00  0.726272  Summer2
93  2021-06-13 00:30:00  0.013616  Summer2
94  2021-06-20 00:30:00  0.947737  Summer2
95  2021-06-27 00:30:00  0.526867  Summer2
96  2021-07-04 00:30:00  0.275155  Summer2
97  2021-07-11 00:30:00  0.318016  Summer2
98  2021-07-18 00:30:00  0.183074  Summer2
99  2021-07-25 00:30:00  0.229309  Summer2
100 2021-08-01 00:30:00  0.560631  Summer2
101 2021-08-08 00:30:00  0.414141  Summer2
102 2021-08-15 00:30:00  0.737118  Summer2
103 2021-08-22 00:30:00  0.809873  Summer2
104 2021-08-29 00:30:00  0.931765  Summer2
105 2021-09-05 00:30:00  0.846052  Autumn3
106 2021-09-12 00:30:00  0.647715  Autumn3
107 2021-09-19 00:30:00  0.360201  Autumn3
108 2021-09-26 00:30:00  0.730339  Autumn3
109 2021-10-03 00:30:00  0.934964  Autumn3
110 2021-10-10 00:30:00  0.174492  Autumn3
111 2021-10-17 00:30:00  0.786723  Autumn3
112 2021-10-24 00:30:00  0.667760  Autumn3
113 2021-10-31 00:30:00  0.203475  Autumn3
114 2021-11-07 00:30:00  0.483362  Autumn3
115 2021-11-14 00:30:00  0.421646  Autumn3
116 2021-11-21 00:30:00  0.221572  Autumn3
117 2021-11-28 00:30:00  0.762433  Autumn3
118 2021-12-05 00:30:00  0.056316  Winter3
119 2021-12-12 00:30:00  0.340162  Winter3


Thank you. Its working to get the desired output.
